# Pluto not finding interface on a ipsec VPN

Tags: vpn, ipsec, vps

I'm trying to setup ipsec however pluto appears not to bind to a public IP and IPsec Kernel requires updating.

This is what I've come up with so far:
-IPSec Verify states my kernel is not supporting IPsec

-I've had the VPS provider enable IPSec in the openvz environment on the host machine however they state I have to rebuild the kernel and provided me a link to the linux kernel archive site for generic linux kernels.

-I've tried building the kernel and installing it but I cannot seem to get it to install properly. The last step I do is 'mkinitramfs -o initrd.img-3.16.3 3.16.3'

-tutorials state to do stuff with grub, however I am on a VPS and don't think grub is even on my VPS image? One tutorial I followed: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

- I tried some grub commands and nothing seems to be there. How do you write a kernel to a VPS container from within the container?

-I had given up on building from source and found *.deb kernel packages and tried installing them, they seemed to unpack and no errors came from it but when I rebooted it was still the old kernel, is there a special command you use with dpkg-buildpackage to make it install? Is it having issues installing due to no boot loader since it's a VPS?(assuming a container doesn't hold a boot loader?)

here is my ipsec output but I think part of the issue is the kernel:

```
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec_setup: Starting Openswan IPsec 2.6.41...
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec_setup: Using NETKEY(XFRM) stack
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec_setup: multiple ip addresses, using  127.0.0.2 on venet0
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec_setup: ...Openswan IPsec started
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec__plutorun: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy pluto: adjusting ipsec.d to /etc/ipsec.d
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec__plutorun: 002 added connection description "L2TP-PSK-noNAT"
Sep 18 04:36:45 shiftmy ipsec__plutorun: 003 no public interfaces found
```

here is my interfaces file, I read somewhere that ipsec binds to the default interface that is first in the interface list. in this case venet0 127.0.0.2 while the public IP is on venet0:0 107.161.xx.xx(not sure if this is the issue) My VPS providers interfaces file is locked so I cannot modify that part, I believe all traffic goes from 107.161.xx.xx through 127.0.0.2 which connects to the openvz host machine aka gateway.

```
root@shiftmy:/etc/network# cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This configuration file is auto-generated.
#
# WARNING: Do not edit this file, your changes will be lost.
# Please create/edit /etc/network/interfaces.head and
# /etc/network/interfaces.tail instead, their contents will be
# inserted at the beginning and at the end of this file, respectively.
#
# NOTE: it is NOT guaranteed that the contents of /etc/network/interfaces.tail
# will be at the very end of this file.
#

# Auto generated lo interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Auto generated venet0 interface
auto venet0
iface venet0 inet manual
        up ifconfig venet0 up
        up ifconfig venet0 127.0.0.2
        up route add default dev venet0
        down route del default dev venet0
        down ifconfig venet0 down


iface venet0 inet6 manual
        up route -A inet6 add default dev venet0
        down route -A inet6 del default dev venet0

auto venet0:0
iface venet0:0 inet static
        address 107.161.xx.xx
        netmask 255.255.255.255
```

I have been searching the net for "ipsec__plutorun: 003 no public interfaces found" issues and can't find much help. Not sure if this is even the real problem as I believe I setup the interfaces correctly.

ipsec verify also fails:

```
Version check and ipsec on-path                         [OK]
Openswan U2.6.41/K(no kernel code presently loaded)
See `ipsec --copyright' for copyright information.
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                    [FAILED]

 The ipsec service should be started before running 'ipsec verify'

Hardware random device check                            [N/A]
Two or more interfaces found, checking IP forwarding    [OK]
Checking rp_filter                                      [ENABLED]
 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/rp_filter                  [ENABLED]
Checking that pluto is running                          [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                     [FAILED]
 Pluto listening for IKE on tcp 500                     [NOT IMPLEMENTED]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on udp 4500              [DISABLED]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on tcp 4500              [NOT IMPLEMENTED]
 Pluto listening for IKE on tcp 10000 (cisco)           [NOT IMPLEMENTED]
Checking NAT and MASQUERADEing                          [TEST INCOMPLETE]
Checking 'ip' command                                   [OK]
Checking 'iptables' command                             [OK]

ipsec verify: encountered errors
```

I've read it can fail if ipsec isn't started correctly and show false failures in some sections of the checklist. IPsec seems to be 'running', i'm not sure if Kernel support is truly not there or if that's a false failure? Also not sure how to fix the pluto failure.

I have followed various guides and cannot seem to get over this issue.

ipsec config:

```
root@shiftmy:/etc/network# cat /etc/ipsec.conf
version 2.0     # conforms to second version of ipsec.conf specification

config setup
        interfaces=%defaultroute
        dumpdir=/var/run/pluto/
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12,%v4:25.0.0.0/8,%v6:fd00::/8,%v6:fe80::/10
        oe=off
        protostack=auto
        protostack=netkey
        force_keepalive=yes
        keep_alive=60

conn L2TP-PSK-noNAT
        authby=secret
        pfs=no
        auto=add
        keyingtries=3
        ikelifetime=8h
        keylife=1h
        ike=aes256-sha1;modp1024!
        phase2alg=aes256-sha1;modp1024
        type=transport
        left=107.161.xx.xx
        leftprotoport=17/1701
        right=%any
        rightprotoport=17/%any
        dpddelay=10
        dpdtimeout=20
        dpdaction=clear
```

ipsec secrets:

```
root@shiftmy:/etc/network# cat /etc/ipsec.secrets
107.161.xx.xx %any: PSK "<key here>"
#include /var/lib/openswan/ipsec.secrets.inc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this one in the end was that openVZ VPS providers have to have a kernel that supports ipsec and must enable ipsec modules on the host machine. Some of our providers would not do this as its a big change for the host machine. Instead we found all our providers supported the openvpn protocol and we enabled 'tun' on all our openvz VPS's with our providers.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue trying to get openswan/ipsec/pluto working in a Docker container.  With my exact same basic configuration, it worked on a VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine.

The problem I had was running an Ubuntu 14.04 image with Docker on my host Arch Linux machine.

I believe the essence of the problem is this line:

```
pluto[439]: no public interfaces found
```

To really dig into this, I had to go to the source code:

```
apt-get source openswan
```

Which can be traced to the source code here:

```
    openswan-2.6.38/programs/pluto/server.c:462:find_ifaces(void)                         
    openswan-2.6.38/programs/pluto/sysdep_bsd.c:201: find_raw_ifaces4(void)               
    openswan-2.6.38/programs/pluto/server.c:477:loglog(RC_LOG_SERIOUS, "no public interfaces found");
```

Whereas on VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04, it finds eth0 and its address just fine.

In essense, it might be this code that is not returning any interfaces:

```
    openswan-2.6.38/programs/pluto/sysdep_bsd.c:243: find_raw_ifaces4() : if (ioctl(master_sock, SIOCGIFCONF, &ifconf) == -1)
```

So in an effort to solve this, I found that Docker limits the access to network devices (it creates a bridge to the host by default) and loading/unloading kernel modules (ipsec loads and unloads kernel modules).  So I had to grant Docker access to everything, including using my host's raw network interface:

```
docker run --cap-add=ALL --net=host -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

Even though this isn't a complete answer to the question, hopefully it will lead others down a path to figuring out what is wrong with their own configuration.  Ideally pluto would give more information on what network devices it finds and why the other aren't suitable (i.e. aren't public).